# tenses :: situations

Tags: present-tense

> Ole Thorstensen’s tales reveal the ruminative side of a physical and demanding line of work.

The above sentence is from *The Economist*. It looks to be written in the present simple tense. Among the uses of present simple which situation is showing this sentence?

Comment: Please edit the title to better describe the question/

Answer (score 3):

The first and most important use of the simple present tense is:

> To express habits, general truths, repeated actions or unchanging situations, emotions and wishes: -- [source](http://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-tense/)

This is the use here. It is stating a general fact, or an unchanging situation about Ole Thorstensen’s tales.

Answer (score 0):

In English, descriptions and accounts of past literary works are traditionally cast in the present tense: they are in effect held to be speaking to today's reader as if actually present—which indeed they are!